# Meaning of 二次遭難{にじそうなん}

Tags: meaning, compounds

Context: the speaker was in a bad situation but got out of it, and has the expectation that the other party is going to scold him for his carelessness.

> あれだけ注意したのに、まんまと**二次遭難**してバカだと思ってるんだろ？　ほんと、その通りだよ

What is the meaning of 二次遭難{にじそうなん} here? Dictionary defines 「二次」 as "secondary" and 「遭難」 as "accident" or "being stranded". Being stranded would somehow describe the nature of the situation, but I don't get the "secondary" part.

If the word has uses in other contexts, I would like to know about them, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「二次遭難{にじそうなん}」 is an accident that could happen to you while you are trying to rescue another that has already been in a (different) accident.　It is **derivative** in nature.

「二次」 here means "secondary" only in the sense that it takes place ***after*** the original accident.

Unless the story you are reading is about an accident in mountain climbing, 「遭難」 is being used figuratively, which is quite common.

A far more comon word would be 「二次[災害]{さいがい}」.

Comment: No mountain climbing here. Accepting this answer for the alternative, more common word.

Answer (score 1):

> 二次{にじ}遭難{そうなん}

とは、

遭難{そうなん}した人{ひと}の救助{きゅうじょ}に向{む}かった者{もの}／人{ひと}が再{ふたた}び遭難{そうなん}すること。

**【English】**

> 二次{にじ}遭難{そうなん}

is;

Those (=A) who rescue those (=B) who were distressed at the (first) accident again (secondary) could be distressed at the related accident.
The first accident may be pure accidental, but the second accident could be expected. So those who rescue should take care more than that of those who were didtressed at the first accident. If those who rescue take the same care as that of the first ones and got ditressed, they could be said "バカ silly/stupid/foolish" for their carelessness.

Comment: Thanks! Where is that Japanese definition from, btw? Or did you write it yourself

Comment: 遭難した人の救助に向かった者が再び遭難する。is my original difinition.

Comment: Ok. The definition was really concise and captured the meaning I was looking for, so I tought there was some Japanese equivalent of the Concise Oxford English Dictionary that I wasn't aware of. Didn't find the word on [コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/) or any other major web dictionary so it must be pretty uncommon when used with 遭難 and not 災害.